# Is WebSocket 'better' than HTTP when used as a simple stateless Web Service Server?

Tags: http, websocket

I've read some articles comparing the differences between WebSocket and the other push methods like Long polling. All the conclusions tend to be WebSocket is better then HTTP with low latency in the server and client bidirectional communication process.
But if server push is not a must, for example, a client game program just make a few queries to the server for some information, does it still better to use WebSocket then HTTP? More specially, I have two doubts here:
1. In a single Request-Response procedure, which is more efficency ? (I establish a WebSocket connection each time querying in the above case.)
2. Will the server capacity (The total number of clients that the server can serve) be affected by the unnecessary long-lived connection if I keep an WebSocket connection during the life cycle of the client?

Added Question:
3. Suppose there is only one TCP connection between the server and the client, will the stability of the connection go down and down as time flows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic thing behind both the **WebSocket** and **HTTP** is the **socket**. In HTTP, it opens a connection on request and closes on response. For WebSocket, concept is a 2 way communication (full duplex) rather than request-response cycle.

Answers to your question:

1. Either you can use HTTP server or can create request-response design
   using WebSocket
2. That's obvious. Each connection is a socket object. Server capacity
       will be affected if we are not managing connections.
3. In WebSocket, it's using **ping-pong** mechanism to make sure that the client or
   the server is alive. For every **ping** requests from one end, other end is
   subjected to reply a **pong** response. This mechanism helps to detect failures and hence to maintain stability.

Comment: Thank you! I've added another question.